# Granting access token manually MVC Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I am allowing user registration to MVC Web API from an App. The app passes Email but no password. I add the user and assign a random password which I mail to the user.

I don't want the app to make two calls to api to get the token.
So, to this request I want to return an oauth token which `/token` endpoint returns.

I was trying this but the token from this request gets Access Denied.
What am I missing here? If there is a better way, much appreciated.

Web API has the default configs like Web API Template. Nothing custom. I would like to keep it this way.

```
        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        Claim providerKeyClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, model.Email, ClaimValueTypes.String, "DrySignup", "DrySignup");

        ExternalLoginData externalLogin = new ExternalLoginData
        {
            LoginProvider = providerKeyClaim.Issuer,
            ProviderKey = providerKeyClaim.Value,
            UserName = identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)
        };

        var info = new ExternalLoginInfo()
        {
            DefaultUserName = model.Email,
            Login = new UserLoginInfo(providerKeyClaim.Issuer, externalLogin.ProviderKey)
        };

        result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        IEnumerable<Claim> claims = externalLogin.GetClaims();
        identity.AddClaims(claims);
        Authentication.SignIn(identity);

        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
        var currentUtc = new Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.SystemClock().UtcNow;
        ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
        ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
        var accessToken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
        Request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);



        // Create the response building a JSON object that mimics exactly the one issued by the default /Token endpoint
        JObject token = new JObject(
            new JProperty("userName", user.UserName),
            new JProperty("userId", user.Id),
            new JProperty("access_token", accessToken),
            new JProperty("token_type", "bearer"),
            new JProperty("expires_in", TimeSpan.FromDays(9999).TotalSeconds.ToString()),
            new JProperty("issued", currentUtc.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'")),
            new JProperty("expires", currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(365)).ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'"))
        );
        return Ok(token);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This works.

```
ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType);

oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id));

AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, new AuthenticationProperties());

DateTime currentUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));

string accessToken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
Request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);



// Create the response building a JSON object that mimics exactly the one issued by the default /Token endpoint
JObject token = new JObject(
    new JProperty("userName", user.UserName),
    new JProperty("userId", user.Id),
    new JProperty("access_token", accessToken),
    new JProperty("token_type", "bearer"),
    new JProperty("expires_in", TimeSpan.FromDays(365).TotalSeconds.ToString()),
    new JProperty("issued", currentUtc.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'")),
    new JProperty("expires", currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(365)).ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'"))
);

return Ok(token);
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day.

Comment: I ended up doing this which is also what I use for external login, I tried using OWIN TestServer as some suggests to call the token endpoint but is no use, in some projects it works in my didn't

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your problem, is you can't issue tokens that way and use the built in OAuthProvider.

You can still kind of what you want by setting this function as the `AuthorizeEndpointPath` in the `OAuthServerOptions`.

If you do that though you will have to send `response_type=token&client_id=something&redirect_uri=/index.html` query params as part of the request and then what you will get back is a 302 with the access token as part of the url. Something like:
`http://example.com/index.html/#access_token={long token string here}&token_type=bearer&expires_in=1209600`

Then in you controller function your code would look something like this

```
ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync("email@example.com");
ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);


AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);
Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity);

return Ok();
```

Your second options would be to implement a custom grant type. This would allow you to call the /token service and create an account. On you OAuthProvider class you would want to override the `GranCustomExtension` function.

```
public override async Task GrantCustomExtension(OAuthGrantCustomExtensionContext context)
        {
            var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var email = context.Parameters["Email"];
            var createUser = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = email, Email = email };

            IdentityResult result = await userManager.CreateAsync(createUser, "Som3R@ndomPassword");

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return;
            }

            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);


            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
              OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);

            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
            context.Validated(ticket);
        }
```

Then you would be able to post to /token with a form-urlencoded request with something like this `grant_type=create&Email=test3%40example.com` and your response would be the same as if you did a `password` `grant_type`